# grouping data by multiple columns

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, plyr

I have many records of data to group by columns names.

```
Name  Surname  value
al     adams    120
al     adams    514
al     bats     220
al     bats     120
bill   cox      440
bill   cox      320
bill   brit     320
```

I want to group by Name and Surname (and keep them), with the sum of Value.
here is my code. I don't get the desired display.

```
DT<-base_AA_P1 %>%  select(Name, Surname) %>% group_by(Name, Surname) %>%  summarize(SUM_value = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: `ave(df$value, as.numeric(as.factor(paste(df$Name, df$Surname))), FUN = sum)` **OR** `aggregate(df$value, by = list(df$Name, df$Surname), sum)`

Comment: Your call to `select` is removing the value column, so that it cannot be called in `summarize`. Removing the `select` part of the chain should work.

Comment: @ d.b it works pretty good but i will remane the columns. thanks !

Comment: @ George when removing the select part, the result is a (1*1) dataframe which is not the desired target.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
data = data.frame(Name = c("al","al","al","al","bill","bill","bill"),
                  Surname = c("adams","adams","bats","bats","cox","cox","brit"),
                  value = c(120,514,220,120,440,320,320))


library(dplyr)

data2 = data %>%
  group_by(Name,Surname)%>%
  summarise(new_value = sum(value))

data2

    Name Surname new_value
1     al   adams       634
2     al    bats       340
3   bill    brit       320
4   bill     cox       760
```

I think that if you select name and surname you will not have the sum of values in the final data you want.

Comment: I have try your solution, data2 (1 col ans 1 row) has just displayed the sum of value, which is not what it expected. ;(

Comment: If you run my code it's impossible than data2 has only 1 row and 1 column. I've even put what data2 is and you can see that you've got your sums for each Name-Surname combinaisons